# Set an operation to a variable

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to get the age average for each car, when I declare a variable the output is the same for all cars.

```
DECLARE @AgeCar INT;
SET @AgeCar = (
    SELECT AVG(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - Year) 
    FROM Car_description
);

SELECT DISTINCT cm.Model, cd.Make,  COUNT(*) AS Sample, @AgeCar AS AvgCarAge
FROM Car_description cd JOIN car_model cm ON cd.Vin_ID=cm.Vin
GROUP BY cm.Model, Make
HAVING COUNT(Model) > 1000
ORDER BY AvgCarAge;
```

I got the same average for all cars, any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you supply sample data and expected results; that would be a big help. Thank you.

Comment: "I got the same average for all cars" - the average is set to a constant value `@AgeCar` at the beginiing. You need to calculate that as part of your query.

Comment: `@AgeCar` is a *scalar* variable and contains a **scalar** value; why would you expect it to have a different value for many rows...?

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when  posting. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING will not get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking for help.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead:

```
SELECT cm.Model, cd.Make,  COUNT(*) AS Sample, AVG(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - Year) AS AvgCarAge
FROM Car_description cd JOIN car_model cm ON cd.Vin_ID=cm.Vin
GROUP BY cm.Model, Make
HAVING COUNT(Model) > 1000
ORDER BY AvgCarAge;
```

This will output the average age of each make/model.

In your attempt you calculate the average of all cars first and store that value in a variable. Then you just toss that variable (that has a number stored in it) into your sql, so it's the same for every row.

Comment: Why a `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY`? That's a sign of a flaw in the query, as the `GROUP BY` already returns the data in *distinct* groups.

Comment: @Larnu I just copied/pasted from OPs query and overlooked their distinct. I will scrub that from my answer as I agree that's an oddball code smell. It was unnecessary in their original query and it's unnecessary here.